# Elasticsearch High-level Rest Client: BulkRequest not retaining value outside of For loop

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to use an Elasticsearch BulkRequest. I believe I am having some sort of scope issue, which I cannot for the life of me understand.

```
public void saveAll(Map<I, T> saveRequestMap) {
        BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest();

        for(Map.Entry<I, T> document : saveRequestMap.entrySet()) {
                request.add(indexRequest(document.getKey(), document.getValue()));
                // request.size() here shows the correct number of items
        }

        // request.size() here always shows 0 items (should show 50 if 50 items were added above)
        BulkResponse response = client.bulk(request, DEFAULT_REQUEST_OPTIONS());

}

protected final IndexRequest indexRequest(I id, T entity) {
        return new IndexRequest(indexName)
                        .id(id.toString())
                        .source(mapEntityToJsonString(entity), XContentType.JSON);
}

private mapEntityToJson(T entity) {
        String jsonObject = mapper.toJsonString(entity);
        log.trace("mapped object: {}", jsonOBject);

        return jsonObject;
}
```

If I have 50 items being bulk-indexed, it will fail because Elasticsearch claims there are 0 items. I soon realized that request.add() is not working like I thought it should and the request is losing all IndexRequests created in the for loop.

If I change the code to this, it is able to index properly:

```
public void saveAll(Map<I, T> saveRequestMap) {
        BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest();
        int count = 0;

        for(Map.Entry<I, T> document : saveRequestMap.entrySet()) {
                request.add(indexRequest(document.getKey(), document.getValue()));
                // request.size() here shows the correct number of items
                count++;

                if(count == saveRequestMap.size()) {
                        // request.size() here shows the correct number of items (e.g. 50)
                        BulkResponse response = client.bulk(request, DEFAULT_REQUEST_OPTIONS());
                }
        }
}

protected final IndexRequest indexRequest(I id, T entity) {
        return new IndexRequest(indexName)
                        .id(id.toString())
                        .source(mapEntityToJsonString(entity), XContentType.JSON);
}

private mapEntityToJson(T entity) {
        String jsonObject = mapper.toJsonString(entity);
        log.trace("mapped object: {}", jsonOBject);

        return jsonObject;
}
```

So the question I have:

- Why does request not retain the objects added to it outside of the for loop, even though it was declared outside of the loop?

I have looked at several posts here at SO and haven't found anything that really helps me understand or hint at whats going on.

Thank you!

Comment: how is the above code even compiling, for(Map.Entry<I, T> document : saveRequestMap.entrySet() this line of code, doesn't have closing braces? or is it just copy paste mistake?

Comment: Sorry, was a typo, which I have now corrected.

Comment: @NishikantTayade, was your only purpose to comment on the typo or did you have something constructive to add to this discussion?

Comment: sorry, but was not able to reproduce the issue, as I am full time dev myself got busy, but will give it a try once again.

Comment: Thanks @NishikantTayade!

I am also a full time dev and my coworkers and I couldn't figure out why this was occurring. When we have a list or a map and are adding items to it in a for loop, they retain the items added. It's very strange that we are having this issue with this specific object type and so naturally, despite the fact we found a workaround (second code snippit), we are curious to figure out the behind the scenes cause!

Answer (score 0):

The process of creating and executing bulk requests has undergone changes in the latest version of Elasticsearch. For the most accurate and detailed information on this topic, I recommend consulting the official Elasticsearch Java REST client documentation. You can find the relevant information by visiting the official Elasticsearch website at the following link: [Elasticsearch Java REST Client Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing-bulk.html#_indexing_application_objects)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing-bulk.html#_indexing_application_objects

Comment: This answer has absolutely nothing to do with the original question. I'm well aware of where to find the official documentation of Elasticsearch and the REST client.

The question I had a year and a half ago was: "Why does request not retain the objects added to it outside of the for loop, even though it was declared outside of the loop?".